# How could I avoid == null checking?

Tags: c#, null

Here is my code which is used widely in project, and I'm wondering can I refactor this somehow so I might avoid `== null` checks all the time?

```
 ActiveCompany = admin.Company == null ? false : admin.Company.Active
```

Thanks guys

Cheers

Comment: Well, can `Company` ever be null?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes

Comment: Then you can't avoid checking it! However, can use the null coalescing operator - but that's still checking for null (but without the `==` syntax).

Comment: it depends on which version(6+) of c# are you using. `admin.Company?.Active`

Comment: is admin.Company.Active an int or nullable int?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use  the C# 6: [Null-conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

```
ActiveCompany = admin.Company?.Active == true;
```

The comparison with `true` at the end "converts" the `bool?` to `bool`. You can also use the null coalescing operator to handle the null value as shown by Keith.

Comment: can you write little bit about this approach? This is some C# 6-7 feature and what's that?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/

Answer (score 12):

null coalescing operator chained with null conditional is useful for this kind of thing :-

```
ActiveCompany =  admin.Company?.Active ?? false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself doing this an *awful* lot, you could write an extension method to simplify the code.

For example, suppose you have these classes:

```
public sealed class Company
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

public sealed class MyClass
{
    public Company Company;
}
```

Then you could write an extension method like so:

```
public static class MyClassExt
{
    public static bool IsActiveCompany(this MyClass myClass)
    {
        return myClass.Company?.Active ?? false;
    }
}
```

Which would mean you can write code like:

```
var test = new MyClass();
// ...
bool activeCompany = test.IsActiveCompany();
```

This doesn't make the code much shorter, but some might think it makes it more readable.